# VBA-Selenium run time error, window not found: unable to find element on closed window

Tags: vba, excel, selenium

however I tried, VBA selenium can't find existing element in a loaded page.
Here is the last code I use:

```
Sub TableData()
Dim driver As New WebDriver
Dim sInfo As String

With driver
    .Start "Internet Explorer"
    .Get "http://cvb.manatron.com/Tabs/PropertySearch.aspx"
    .FindElementById("fldInput").SendKeys ("Carter")
    .FindElementById("btnsearch").Click
    sInfo = .FindElementById("grm-search", timeout:=20000).Text
    Debug.Print sInfo
    .Quit
End With

End Sub
```

Hope somebody can help. Thanks

Comment: Probably the web page loads a bit slower than the VBA code runs. Put some 5 seconds wait before `.FindElementById` and try again.

Comment: No matter how long I wait, the page always lag.

Comment: why is your question different from the question title?  which one is correct?

Comment: use this `Dim driver As New ieDriver`

Comment: Sorry for confusing, the title is the correct one.
After changing to 'Dim driver As New ieDriver' it's still not solved.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me by adding a delay before the `SendKeys` and attempting to retrieve `sInfo`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TableData()
Dim driver As New WebDriver
Dim sInfo As String

With driver
    .Start "Chrome" '"Internet Explorer"
    .Get "http://cvb.manatron.com/Tabs/PropertySearch.aspx"
 
     Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:02")

    .FindElementByCss("#fldInput").SendKeys "Carter"
    .FindElementById("btnsearch").Click
     
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")

    sInfo = .FindElementById("grm-search", timeout:=20000).Text
    Debug.Print sInfo
    .Quit
End With

End Sub
```

Output:

[image: Output of search]